# How can I silence SQLPlus compilation warnings?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am working on a project which requires me to make a very small, very surgical change to many (many) different Oracle packages. These packages have other flaws which I am not yet addressing--flaws that the Oracle compiler notes after these warnings:

> Package Body created with compilation warnings

I use SQLPlus to compile all my edits, and spool the output of script execution to log files.

I need to apply my edits, and be able to quickly and easily see compilation errors (without needing to pick through the warnings haystack) in those log files.

How can I turn off compilation warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [the `PLSQL_WARNINGS` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams186.htm), the following command will suppress compilation warnings:

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'DISABLE:INFORMATIONAL';
```